# Confusion with Courant: Which of his two calculus books is THE one?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Since I've worked my way through Spivak's Calculus book, I thought I'd give Courant's allegedly fantastic exposition of the subject a go as well. However, I've run into a problem. People in stackexchange threads always praise and suggest Courant's Calculus without specifying whether that's supposed to be his *"Differential and Integral Calculus"* or his *"Introduction to Calculus and Analysis"* book.

So my question is: which one of these two is the "famous" and "legendary" Calculus book that everybody always talks about when the *"great three"* - Spivak, Apostol and Courant - are mentioned or recommended to people asking for a first course in calculus?

Note: I'm a math major. I'm mostly interested in what the oft-mentioned calculus book by Courant is, and not which of his two books would suit my prior exposure to calculus (Spivak) best in terms of the follow-up level. That is not to say I wouldn't appreciate an informed opinion on that matter, I certainly would (and I hope some experienced readers will be able to enlighten me), but I'm primarily asking this question to find out which is the more canonical one.

Comment: It may be noted that the "contents" section of both texts are almost identical.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these texts myself, but a question similar to yours was asked in another forum, and answered with an excerpt from the preface of the later book: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/introduction-to-calculus-and-differental-and-integral-calculus-courant.387957/ It seems the later *Introduction* is a rewritten version of the earlier *Calculus*. If you've worked through Spivak, my own advice to you would be not to spend time studying single-variable calculus over again in a different introductory book. I would recommend studying either multivariable calculus or...

Comment: ...mathematical analysis at this point (or both). For multivariable calculus, you could use one of Courant's books or Vol. 2 of Apostol.

Comment: @David While I appreciate your reply, you haven't actually answered my question. *"Introduction to Calculus and Analysis"* originally came out in 1965. The fact that its based on his earlier work *"Differential and Integral Calculus"* is entirely irrelevant: it says nothing about which the most canonical work is.

Comment: @David As far as multivariable calculus goes; I'm already learning it. I was planning on going through Courant as a side-project, so to speak. Also, you suggested I could use "one of Courant's books". I know that. That's what this whole question is about. Which one. You just answered my question by raising the exact same question I was trying to find an answer to. Either way, thank you for your input.

Comment: I know that that doesn't answer your question exactly, but it says in the authors' words why the new book was necessary. Searching on the internet, I've found references to both books being very good, alongside Spivak and Apostol. It seems they're almost never mentioned together. It may be that neither one is more "canonical" than the other. This list ( https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm ) mentions the first, and this one (http://dasgupab.faculty.udmercy.edu/calc-books.html ) the second. See here as well: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/calculus-courant-confusion.309600/

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but I've just started reading "Differential and Integral Calculus". It's fantastic. I wish I had it when I was first learning the subject a decade ago--it would have saved me tons of time sorting out the misconceptions that you get from other books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Differential and Integral Calculus* is the classic. The first edition in English came out in 1934. *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis* is a somewhat modified version co-authored by Fritz John. Careful attention to either version will give you (just about the same) very good grounding in calculus, so you may want to read which ever one is easier to get a copy of. But if you want to read the classic, it's *Differential and Integral Calculus*.

Another very lovely, old calculus text is *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G. H. Hardy. It's impossible to learn the subject from the book by Landau (also called *"Differential and Integral Calculus"*), but it's worth a look once you already know the subject.

Comment: Thank you Paul - I had already given up hope of ever having this question answered. I will look into reading *"Differential and Integral Calculus"*, if only for the sake of having it in my collection.