# How different is Courant’s textbook from the one by himself and Fritz John?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, book-recommendation

I have been studying Courant’s “Differential and Integral Calculus” ([https://www.ime.usp.br/~gorodski/ps/Courant-DifferentialIntegralCalculusVolI.pdf](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Egorodski/ps/Courant-DifferentialIntegralCalculusVolI.pdf)) for about a month now, doing all of the problems to each section and, well, struggling. Having completely understood that I liked that textbook, I ordered both volumes on Amazon. However now I find out that there exists another textbook, which originated from the aforementioned one, and it was written by Courant and Fritz John (namely, “Introduction to Calculus and Analysis” [http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/~aceves/Metodos/ebooks/courant_john1.pdf](http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/%7Eaceves/Metodos/ebooks/courant_john1.pdf)). It is now of utmost importance to me to understand whether I went on a folly by buying those books, and it is by asking you: will I miss out on a lot if I read the former instead? Is Courant and John’s book better, more rigorous and does it cover more? I am willing to study calculus and analysis in all of their entirety, so I must now. Please, just tell me no matter how harsh the truth is.

Comment: You should link to the books you're talking about (e.g. what's the title of the third book?)

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. You won't go wrong studying all of them, but start by picking the one that reads most naturally to you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791281/what-is-the-difference-between-richard-courants-differential-and-integral-calc , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645497/confusion-with-courant-which-of-his-two-calculus-books-is-the-one , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156848/courants-introduction-to-calculus-and-analysis-vs-differential-and-integral